# OctopusRepository is returning everything as empty

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am trying to call some Octopus REST APIs from my C# application. However, OctopusRepository is returning every object(such as Spaces) with Count=0. I have error handling in my code. I know the code is able to make successful connection to the Octopus REST API but I am not sure why everything is returned as empty

```
            var endpoint = new OctopusServerEndpoint(octopusURL, octopusAPIKey);
            var repository = new OctopusRepository(endpoint);
            var client = new OctopusClient(endpoint);

            var space = repository.Spaces.FindByName(spaceName);
            var repositoryForSpace = client.ForSpace(space);

            // Get projects
            var projects = repositoryForSpace.Projects.GetAll();

            // Get library set
            var librarySet = repositoryForSpace.LibraryVariableSets;
```